# user:role:add for email addresses in Drush 9/10?

Tags: drush

In Drush 8, you can [add a role to an email address](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/user/user-add-role/) like this:

```
drush user-add-role "power user" --mail=penguin@example.com
```

In Drush 9, [the --mail option no longer exists](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/user/user:role:add/) for `user:role:add`.

So, if I only have an email address, how can I add a role to the user account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe there are better ways, but the following should work:

```
drush user-add-role "power user" $(drush user-information --mail=penguin@example.com --field=name)
```

You get the user name from the e-mail address using the user-information command.